# When is a variable considered constant in terms of PEP8 naming styles?

Tags: python, pep8

In keeping with PEP8 conventions, in a `.py` I can define constants as:

```
NAME = "Me"
AGE = "Old"
GENER = "Male"
```

If  a `.txt` contained `Me Old Male` on a single line, and in another `.py` I performed:

```
FILE = "C:/path/to/file.txt"  # a declared constant, easy
with open(FILE, 'r') as f:
    content = f.read().rstrip('\n').split()
    data = ','.join(content)  # returns Me,Old,Male
```

**Question(s):**

Can `content` and `data` be considered constants?

To be constant, must a variable be declared as a constant at build?

Or is constant vice variable a function of the ability to be altered by user input in runtime?

**Supporting Informaton:**

`content` is what is in the file, but it is subject to `.rstrip()` and `.split()` but it as a whole is never changed later. `data` is made from `content`, which hasn't changed and wont, and is subject to `.join()`. Neither values change after they are initialized.

I would view this similar to:

```
>>> A = 2  # a declared constant
>>> B = 2  # another declared constant
>>> TOTAL = A + B  # 'caps' per PEP8 for constant naming
4
```

Assuming the program has terminated and `TOTAL` is never altered, I would consider this value a constant. Again under the presumption that any variable that is not alterable during runtime is to be considered a constant.

Feel free to alter my notions as required to align with standards!

Comment: I don't think you should be opening files anywhere where you are defining constants.

Comment: @Artyer Assume this is a simple program where the filename will always be the same; thus its declaration `FILE` is constant. I'm asking w.r.t. the resultants pulled into the variables `content` & `data` are also considered constant if they never change for the remainder of the program.

Comment: Python does not have *un-alterable* user variables.

Comment: Python doesn't have constants. As you noted, the PEP8 style is simply just that: _a style_. Python doesn't enforce constant-ness on any variable. Which means any variable you want can be _considered_ constant or non constant. So the premise of your question really doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @wwii Look at this w.r.t. PEP8 conventions please. Not functionality or use of the variables in question.

Comment: @ChristianDean Well in keeping with PEP8, would those meet the _style_ criteria for constant or variable? Where is the line to determine that? Is it if the item is single use or reusable, has methods called against it? Etc...

Comment: @madeslurpy: it is generally a bad idea to load files on module import, is what Artyer is hinting at.

Comment: The only style criteria for constants is `ALL_CAPS_WITH_UNDERSCORES`. As long as you do not do anything to changes the assigned value of that "constant" then it is for all intensive purposes a constant.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I followed up to your answer with a tertiary question about loading files on module import.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are going to treat the value as a constant in the rest of your code, by all means, use `CONSTANT_CASE` for those globals. It's up to you, it's merely a documentation convention.

In other words, it's a convention that aims to make it easier for *future readers of your code* to understand that the value of such a global is set just once and is expected not to change over the lifetime of the program.

Note that I'd generally try to avoid loading file data on module import; it makes it harder to test and impacts performance. Load that data on first use instead (using a function).

Comment: I like to be thorough and inline with practice standards. Thanks for the clean response! To follow up, why is having a file path declared in a program bad practice? It is used in a script that is designed to have user data auto-gathered each time the run the script so they don't have to supply a path to their info each time.

Comment: What is meant by "Load that data on first use instead (using a function)?

Comment: Test if that data is read when you need access to it, and if not, *then* read it and cache the data. Put that logic in a function so you can test it with a unittest.

Comment: So declaring the path as a constant is fine on load, but I don't get why I cant then just sequentially read the data into a variable? What if that is the first thing I need to do? Run `.py`, imports modules, then has to read that file to get `data` before moving on. Are you suggesting to check if `data` is `NULL` and if so, then go read?

Comment: @madeslurpy: yes, but now importing your module incurs extra I/O on import, increasing the risk that something goes wrong at that time and making it harder to write tests for your code (certainly for the code that loads the data).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confounding notions of constant variables with actual data held in a file. Python does not really have a notion of constants like C or Java do. Thus, the notation of declaring constant variables with upper-cased variable names is only a convention to tell the programmer (you), that you are dealing with a variable that shouldn't be changed, but that python won't restrict you from doing so.

The only way that I can think of, to a "real" constant is to make it an attribute in a class, and restrict the `__setattr__`:

```
class Constant:
    def __init__(self, name, age, gender):
        self.__dict__["NAME"] = name
        self.__dict__["AGE"] = age
        self.__dict__["Gender"] = gender

    def __setattr__(self, a, v):
        raise TypeError("Cannot set attributes of '{}' class".format(str(self.__class__).rsplit('.',1)[1]))
```

Thus, you can read the attributes, but won't be able to set them:

```
In [131]: c = Constant("Me", "Old", "Male")

In [132]: c.NAME
Out[132]: 'Me'

In [133]: c.NAME = 'd'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-133-d979661dfd1d> in <module>()
----> 1 c.NAME = 'd'

<ipython-input-130-9a8604514ac4> in __setattr__(self, a, v)
      6 
      7     def __setattr__(self, a, v):
----> 8         raise TypeError("Cannot set attributes of '{}' class".format(str(self.__class__).rsplit('.',1)[1]))

TypeError: Cannot set attributes of 'Constant'>' class
```

Comment: I think your missing the premise of his question(as did I). He is asking what are the general guidelines for when you should make a variable "constant" in Python. Not how constant-ness could be implemented.

Comment: Appreciate the response but not in the scope of what I was asking. I've read about this by Alex Martellis [AS](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/65207-constants-in-python/).